# Hidden files on memory card

Tags: trash, files.app

I recently checked one of my memory card for space to add some video footage. The card had 11+GB of space, and is using 4.6 GB, but the video footage was 13GB. I was disappointed, as I was running low on available cards. I opened the card to see if I could move some of what was there to make space. There was one folder with, surprise, four documents. So, I was perplexed as to why four documents was using 4.6GB of space. I checked further and the folder (Files) was in fact using only 13.6 MB of space. So there was something else on the card that was hidden. I "unhide", and there were three more files: .fseventsd, .Spotlight-v100 and .Trashes. The .Trashes had 4.6GB of stuff (trash).
My questions: Why are these files hidden, and why is there a file with Trashes still on my card taking up all that space? Should I delete it? can it even be deleted?
Any help with this issue is appreciated.
Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

When you send something to the Trash in the Finder, it gets moved to the `.Trash` folder on the disk. If you want to delete it, you have to empty the Trash.
If you want to delete the files inside the Trash folder, then you can delete them. Don't delete the .Trash folder itself.

The Spotlight file is, as you can guess, a file relating to the Spotlight index. The .fseventsd folder is also part of the file system, relating to file changes on the disk.

You should not delete the Spotlight folder, nor the fseventsd folder.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt and clear response. I'm saying though, that the trash is on the memory card (hidden). And the Trash (in the Dock) is empty...at least now. I take it then, that the fix is to delete the files in the .Trash folder (files only),

Comment: @Radam13 Usually, the GUI Trash folder should include the .Trash folder from any mounted drive. So something may have gone screwy.